# Django form ajax submit concurrently

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms

I have some field created by **Django form** and there are some other data I want to post to other form using **jQuery(Ajax)**.
Is there any way to post them to different tables with two different ways at the same time?

**form.py**

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Planning
        fields = ['title','description','open','owner','upload_time']
```

**template**

```
            <form id="myform" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %} 
                {{ form.management_form }}
                <div id="select_country">
                    <p style="display: inline;">country</p>
                    <select id="city">
                        <option selected disabled hidden>please choose</option>
                        {% for x in areas %}
                        <option value="{{x.area_country}}">{{x.area_country}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                    <select id="areas" name="my_areas"></select>
                    <br>
                    <div class="my_detail">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div id="content_loi" class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="col-lg-12" id="list"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12"">
                        <label>title:{{form.title}}</label>
                        <p><b>description:</b>{{form.description}}</p>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="margin:0 auto;">submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

I want to store the chosen areas and foreign key to another table with ajax

**view**

```
def make_list(request):
    template = get_template('index.html')
    areas = models.Area.objects.values('area_country').distinct() 
    max_my_id = models.RoutePlanning.objects.all().aggregate(Max('my_id')) 
    my_id = int(max_my_id['my_id__max']) + 1 
    #city = request.POST.get('my_areas')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.MyForm(request.POST,initial={'owner':username,'route_id':my_id,'route_upload_time':datetime.now()})

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/make_player')
    else:
        loi_form = forms.MyForm(initial={'owner':username,'route_id':my_id,'route_upload_time':datetime.now()})
    request_context = RequestContext(request)
    request_context.push(locals())
    html = template.render(request_context)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: What do you mean post them to different tables? Can you give an example?

Comment: I mean store into two different tables.

Comment: What do you mean post them to different tables? Can you give an example?

Comment: You can send any data you like through ajax, it doesn't have to be form data, and in your view you can store them in what ever table you want.

Comment: OK, I give some example.

Comment: You can give your button an id name and onclick call a function that will send the data concurrently. Is this what you wanted to accomplish?